# Casting a String as Integer in a .net DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, csv, datatable

Disclaimer: This is my very first .net c# project

I am attempting to import a CSV into MSSQL but need to iterate through the CSV values first for sanitization purposes. Some of the columns in the CSV will be integer (will be used for calcuations later) and some are regular varchar.

My script above appears to force all values (that is row column values) in the DataTable as a string which throws an Exception later in my application when SQL cannot write a string as an integer.

Here is my method I am using for the getCSVImport which creates a datatable and populates it.

What I am thinking is to add another condition which checks if the value is an integer and then cast it as an integer (this kind of thing is new to me as PHP would does not handle types so strongly) but I fear that wont work as I am not sure if I can mix the values within a dataTable with various types.

So my question is, is there a way for me to have different values in a datatable as different types? My code below takes the line as a whole and writes it as a string, I need the values to be assigned either as string or as integer.

```
   /*
     * getCsvData()
     * This method will create a datatable from the CSV file. We'll take the CSV file as is.
     * and collect the data as needed:
     * 
     *  - Remove those original 4 lines (worthless info)
     *  - Line 5 starts with the headers, remove any of the brackets around the values
     *  - Iterate through the rest of the fields and sanitize them before we add it to the datatable
     *  
     */

    private DataTable getCsvData(string csv_file_path)
    {
        // Create a new csvData tabletable object:
        DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
            {
                csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                int row = 1;
                while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                {
                    // Read the string and collect the row data
                    string[] rowData = csvReader.ReadFields();

                    if (row <= 4)
                    {
                        // We want to start on row 5 as first rows are nonsense :)
                        // Incriment the row so that we can do our magic above
                        row++;
                        continue;
                    } if(row == 5)
                    {
                        // Row 5 is the headers, we need to sanitize and continue:
                        foreach (string column in rowData)
                        {
                            // Remove the [ ] from the values:
                            var col = column.Substring(1, column.Length - 2);
                            DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(col);
                            datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                            csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                        }
                        // Incriment the row so that we can do our magic above
                        row++;
                    } else
                    {
                        // These are all of the actual rows, sanitize and add the rows:
                        //Making empty value as null
                        for (int i = 0; i < rowData.Length; i++)
                        {
                            // First remove the brackets:
                            if (rowData[i].Substring(0,1) == "[")
                            {
                                rowData[i] = rowData[i].Substring(1, rowData[i].Length - 2);
                            }
                            // Set blank to null:
                            if (rowData[i] == "" || rowData[i] == "-")
                            {
                                rowData[i] = null;
                            }

                            // Lastly, we need to do some calculations:

                        }
                        // Add the sanitized row to the DataTable:
                        csvData.Rows.Add(rowData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not parse the CSV file: "+ ex.Message);
        }
        return csvData;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: You can't "cast" a String to an integer, but you can parse it. Take a look at `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse`.

Comment: Kinetic: Realised I did not ask a question, updated the above :) @Grant - Yes the CSV will be fixed with all future imports (any changes to the CSV will result in code changes)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the string to a int:

```
int j;
bool parsed=Int32.TryParse("-105", out j))
```

With TryParse you can check if it succeeded.

Then when you want to save it to the table again, cast it to string. You can simply do `<variable>.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

By default, [data columns are initialized to a string data type](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataColumn.cs,3eb97722c491c12f,references).

There's an overload that allows you to specify the type, so I'd suggest you try that. Since your columns are known beforehand, you can easily handle this in your code.

```
private DataColumn AddColumn(string columnName, Type columnType)
{
    // Remove the [ ] from the values:
    var col = column.Substring(1, columnName.Length - 2);
    DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn(col, columnType);
    dataColumn.AllowDBNull = true;
    return dataColumn;
}

if (row == 5)
{
    csvData.Columns.Add(AddColumn(rowData[0], typeof(string)));
    csvData.Columns.Add(AddColumn(rowData[1], typeof(int)));
    csvData.Columns.Add(AddColumn(rowData[2], typeof(DateTime)));
    csvData.Columns.Add(AddColumn(rowData[3], typeof(string)));
    // etc
}
```

I'm not sure you'll even need to convert the other values before adding them to the `DataTable`, but if you do, many built-in types have `TryParse` methods, such as `DateTime.TryParse` and `Int32.TryParse`. You can call each of them in succession, and one of the "tries" succeeds, you'll know your type.

Alternatively, since you know the column types beforehand, you can just cast each value.

```
csvData.Rows.Add(Convert.ToString(rowData[0]),
                 Convert.ToInt32(rowData[1]),
                 Convert.ToDateTime(rowData[2]),
                 Convert.ToString(rowData[3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use *.TryParse(), ie: With this sample CSV:

```
*A sample csv file with
*some comment lines at top
-- with different comment 
// comment strings.
[charField],[dateField],[intField],[decimalField]
"Sample char data 1",2016/1/2,123,123.45
"Sample char data 2",,2,1.5
"Sample char data 3",,3,
"Sample char data 4",,,
,,,
"Sample char data 6",2016/2/29 10:20,10,20.5
```

You might use TryParse on those datetime, int, decimal fields:

```
void Main()
{
    var myData = ReadMyCSV(@"c:\MyPath\MyFile.csv");
    // do whatever with myData
}

public IEnumerable<MyRow> ReadMyCSV(string fileName)
{
    using (TextFieldParser tfp = new TextFieldParser(fileName))
    {
        tfp.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        tfp.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });

        //tfp.CommentTokens = new string[] { "*","--","//" };
        // instead of using comment tokens we are going to skip 4 lines
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            tfp.ReadLine();
        }

        // header line.
        tfp.ReadLine();

        DateTime dt;
        int i;
        decimal d;

        while (!tfp.EndOfData)
        {
            var data = tfp.ReadFields();

            yield return new MyRow
            {
                MyCharData = data[0],
                MyDateTime = DateTime.TryParse(data[1], out dt) ? dt : (DateTime?)null,
                MyIntData = int.TryParse(data[2], out i) ? i : 0,
                MyDecimal = decimal.TryParse(data[3], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, null, out d) ? d : 0M
            };
        }
    }
}

public class MyRow
{
    public string MyCharData { get; set; }
    public int MyIntData { get; set; }
    public DateTime? MyDateTime { get; set; }
    public decimal MyDecimal { get; set; }
}
```

I could further sanitize the data loaded, such as:

```
myData.Where( d => d.MyIntData != 0 );
```

Note: I didn't use a DataTable, which I could if I wanted to. For MSSQL loading, I would probably use an intermediate in-memory SQLite instance to save the sanitized data and then push to MSSQL using SqlBulkCopy class. A DataTable is of course an option (I just think it is less flexible).